# Clustered data: GEE VS GLM with robust S.E

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-estimating-equations, clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error, sandwich

I am trying to understand the difference between running a GEE with robust S.E., vs running a GLM where robust S.E could be calculated posthoc based on the model output. For example, if one considers a binary outcome with grouped data, it seem like it could be modeled using either GEE or conventional GLM, where in both cases robust S.E. could be calculated (see here for example: https://grodri.github.io/glms/r/robust).

I'm trying to understand the difference between these approaches. When would one be more correct to use over the other? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, in your example the author shows how to obtain heteroskedasticity-consistent standard errors in a cross-sectional setting. GEEs are used in longitudinal/hierarchical settings where multiple measurement are available for the persons/objects. In this case, GLMs with cluster-robust standard errors should yield the same results as GEEs with an independence working correlation matrix. See: aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/147/7/694.full.pdf+html. Best S.